# Cumulative open subscriptions with start_date and end_date on Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a query that will allow to me to count the number of active subscriptions by day in Redshift.

I have the following table:

```
  sub_id   | start_date |  end_date
  ---------------------------------------
   20001   | 2017-09-01 |   NULL
   20002   | 2017-08-01 | 2017-08-29
   20003   | 2016-01-01 | 2017-04-25
   20004   | 2016-07-01 | 2017-09-03
```

I would like to be able to state, for each date between two dates how many subscriptions are active, such that:

```
      date    | active_subs
  ------------------------
  2016-06-30  |  1
  2016-07-01  |  2
    ...       |
  2017-04-24  |  2
  2017-04-25  |  1
    ...       |
  2017-07-31  |  1
  2017-08-01  |  2
    ...       |
  2017-08-28  |  2
  2017-08-29  |  1
  2017-08-30  |  1
  2017-08-31  |  1
  2017-09-01  |  2
  2017-09-02  |  2
  2017-09-03  |  1
```

I have a reference table from which a query can draw 1 row per day with the table name of date and the relevant column being date.ref_date (in the YYYY-MM-DD format)

Do i write this query using window functions or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you don't need nor window functions, joins(except to the date table) or cumulative count. You can do this:

```
SELECT t.date,
       COUNT(s.sub_id) as active_subs
FROM dateTable t
LEFT JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.dateCol between s.start_date 
              AND COALESCE(s.end_date,<Put A late date here>))
GROUP BY t.date
```

Comment: of course, when someone else writes it out so simply it makes obvious sense. I was trying to over complicate it. Thanks @sagi!

Comment: @Ozmoges . . . I would suggest you try the solution with window functions.  It should have better performance on Redshift.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're right about performances(not sure there will be any major difference), but the maintenance for this query will be harder.. New programmers often get confused from window functions.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as:

```
with cte as (
      select start_date as dte, 1 as inc
      from t
      union all
      select coalesce(end_date, current_date), -1 as inc
      from t
     )
select dte,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte)
from cte
group by dte
order by dte;
```

There may be off-by-one errors, depending on whether you count stops on the date given or on the next day.

Comment: Redshift doesn't support recursive CTEs and even if it did that is an overkill for such a simple query. `BETWEEN` in join condition like in the other answer is very simple and works well here

Comment: There is nothing recursive about this CTE.  This is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: yeah you're right, it's not recursive, but I would argue the join is much cleaner